# How to convert Powermath to mathml equations?

Tags: xml, math, mathml

I want to convert all the powermath equations into mathml equation. Can anyone suggest a way to do this process?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get a shovel or write a parser/converter.  Better yet, have a look at LaTeX with its Javascript implementations (e.g. KaTeX https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/)

Comment: You can export them form InDesign http://phsoftware.com/powermath/?page_id=494. Other than that you will need to write a parser.

Comment: Hi Salix alba i had a look at your link it helps me lot but i need a same kind of tool for windows.. Can any one suggest